# C# Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word calculate text height

Tags: c#, ms-word, interop

I’m writing an application that outputs a word file containing text an images. The blocks of text are of variable length. In some cases I want to know how much vertical space a block of text wil use in the document, given a certain width, so I can insert a page break to make it look nicer.

I’m using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word

So the question is: Is it possible to calculate the resulting height given a certain width and a certain text style.

Cheers!

Comment: It's sort of possible but not extremely accurate. *However* Word's on-board formatting rules makes it possible to achieve good page breaking without needing to do this or using manual page breaks. This is really more an end-user topic but in a nutshell: Take a look at the Paragraphs dialog box, the "Line and Page breaks" tab. This lets you set which paragraphs should keep all their lines together on a page, and which paragraphs should always stay together on a page. Plus there's "Widow Orphan control" which ensures that more than one or two lines of a paragraph are at the start/end of a page.

Comment: Continuing... These settings, as part of STYLE definitions, enable a fine-grained control of how Word lays out the page. So when the content is edited (changing the amount of text) Word will automatically adjust where the page breaks.

Comment: Hi Cindy! Thanks for helping. The problem is a block of info can consist of a rectangular shape with a title, than an page wide image and underneath that a block of text. It would look weird if, for instance, the bar and the image were on one page and the text on the next. I cant find how to make rules for that... And maybe Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word isn't the right tool to use? Any suggestions for other, better tools are welcome.

Comment: How would you split this particular example up, then? My inclination in any case would be to keep everything "in-line" with the text which would mean a table for the title and the image, possibly also the text in a third row...

Comment: AH! I never thought to use tables! My first version built a pdf file and i was able to use x,y coords to place stuf. So my approach was all wrong! Sounds like using tables is the way to go. Thanks a lot Cindy!